# unable to open two links at a time using window.open() and header functions

Tags: php

on opening of page i want 2 links to open one from field "link" and other  "http://myprojects.com"

the code works without window.open link i.e without trying to open myprojects.com in a new window but gives error call to undefined function open(); when window.open is present.

without window.opem it redirects to the link from the link custom field

```
<?php
ob_start();
get_header();

$value= strip_tags(get_field('link',$post));

window.open("http://myprojects.com","_blank"); 

if( $value ) {    
header('Location: '.$value);
die();
} else {} 

get_sidebar();
get_footer();

?>
<?php
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

i understand that window.open() is a javascript code...how else do i get another link to open as a popup or second window

Comment: `window.open` is a function in Javascript. What you have here is PHP. I don't know what your expected result of "opening two links" is.

Answer (score 0):

it's not php - it's javascript

```
window.open("http://myprojects.com","_blank");
```

window.open() will not open in new tab if it is not happening on actual click event. In the example given the url is being opened on actual click event. This will work provided user has appropriate settings in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You have added `window.open("http://myprojects.com","_blank");` inside the php tag.

Its a javascript code not a php one..
`